# What does Angular 2 CLI use for module loading and bundling?

Tags: angular, webpack

Does Angular 2 CLI use Webpack Or SystemJS? For module bundling? I thought they used to use SystemJS but I've been seeing stuff lately that they use webpack now.  Why did they switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used to use SystemJS. [As of 2016-08-02 they now use Webpack](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/ed5f47dc22d5eb4a5d4b4ae2c8f7cb0ec1a999f3/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta11-webpack-2016-08-02). Check out the changelog to understand some of their reasoning behind making the switch.

Major points copied directly from changelog:

This is kind of a big deal, really. This will mean less thinking about the internals of the CLI and SystemJS, less time spent configuring a new npm package and karma, your life is going to be much easier! More coding where it actually matters, faster builds, more time spent with your loved ones, and lots of other goodies. Just for you. You'll love it!